# Apple Pay Web - determine supported client version

Tags: applepay, applepayjs, applepay-web

What is a good way to determine what Apple Pay web SDK version does the web client support?

In checking the documentation only found [supportsVersion(number): boolean](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaysession/1778014-supportsversion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found no other way than to iterate against all the versions until you find one that works.

```js
static getLatestSupportedVersion(): number {
  if (!this.doesBrowserSupport()) {
    return 0
  }
  // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_on_the_web_version_history
  const LATEST_VERSION = 16
  let applePayVersion = LATEST_VERSION
  while (!this.supportsVersion(applePayVersion) && applePayVersion > 1) {
    --applePayVersion
  }
  return applePayVersion
}

static supportsVersion(number): boolean {
  return window.ApplePaySession.supportsVersion(number)
}

static doesBrowserSupport(): boolean {
  if (window["ApplePaySession"]) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```